# How to find the area under a curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I am confused about an NCERT question from the chapter on the application of intergrals, where it is asked to find the area of the region bounded by the curve $y^2 = x$  and the lines $x = 1$, $x = 4$ and the $x$-axis. The required area is taken from only the first quadrant and has been solved. Should we not be required to multiply the value by $2$ since the area in the fourth quadrant below the $x$-axis is also enclosed by the curve and the two lines?

Here is an [image of the curve and lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmOxA.png).

Comment: The statement _is_ a bit sloppy but the diagram indicates the integration region that you are intended to use.  A proper statement would be to say "the region between the vertical lines, below the curve, _and on or above_ the $ \ x-$ axis ( $ \ y \ge 0 \ $ )".

Comment: @boojum or else they could add simply find area in First quadrant.  what do you think accoding to question..we should multiply by 2 the final area?

Comment: Here is same solution and approach is same they simply have calcualted the area above the x-axis only. https://www.teachoo.com/3325/730/Ex-8.1--1---Find-area--y2--x-and-lines-x--1--4---Chapter-8/category/Ex-8.1/

Comment: Yes, saying "the area in the first quadrant" would also be fine.  Both problems show a shaded region, so there is no question what is intended, however.  So we would _not_ multiply   $ \ \int_1^4 \ \sqrt{x} \ \ dx \ $ by 2 .

Comment: One thing you seem to be overlooking is that the area is **not** described as being bounded by the curve and the two vertical lines, but as being bounded by the curve, two lines *and the $x$-axis*. Thus the axis forms a boundary of the region. It cannot include the full shape you are suggesting. There is still a problem with the wording, in that there are two separate regions bounded by these four curves - one in the first quadrant and one in the fourth. So the wording is ambiguous, but the area of the two regions is the same, so the answer is not ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you @PaulSinclair. Understood.